# C# Input string was not in correct format for MySQL DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, datatable

I looking through the various pieces of information about this, and I couldn't find anything about it after an hour of searching, so I've been forced to ask something specifically.

In my MySQL database, I have a series of tables with a Created_dt column, which is a DateTime(6) field. An example of data would be: `2015-06-19 11:52:07.000000`

I can pull any column from any table in the database except for this one, for some reason. Whenever I make a connection string, and fill a datatable with the adapter, I get the error in the title. Code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Created_dt from comptran_bulk", connection);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd as MySqlCommand);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt); // This is where the exception is thrown, when data is loaded into the table.
```

This command will eventually be replaced with `"Select * from view_Sales"`, and so the solutions to cast it differently I don't think will work. Also, none of the values for `Created_dt` are Null, so Allow Zero `DateTime=True` also didn't work.

What would you suggest?

Comment: What is `cmd2` exactly? On which line you get this `FormatException`?

Comment: A typo from my edits, sorry!

Comment: Added information about the exception line.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was going in an old error ticket in 2012.

> "[1 Jun 2012 13:39] Dan Berger
> This does not seem to be fixed in 6.4.5 - I still get the FormatException.
>
> I can narrow the problem down even more if it helps:
>
> MySqlDateTime Success = new MySqlDateTime("2012-01-01 12:00:00");
>
> MySqlDateTime Failure = new MySqlDateTime("2012-01-01 12:00:00.123456"); // throws FormatException
>
> My server is "MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10", if that makes a difference."

When using this in C# .NET, the microseconds are the cause of the error. After modifying things to become a datetime(0) instead of datetime(6), things have started to work.

Comment: This was caused by the migration wizard, I believe. I was migrating from SQL 2008 R2 to MySql.